# On ru.SO, message warning that you don't have enough privs to perform some action is partly translated

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, голоса-против

When trying to vote down without having enough rep, you got this message where "requires ... reputation" is definitely not in Russian (I guess :D):

> [image]